# Short story: a robot nods but doesn't speak

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

In a tutorial, one of the hardest jobs is coaxing students into actually speaking. Recently a random memory has started coming into my mind when I'm supervising them. A robot is being interviewed, and is asked a question, and its response is described more or less in these words:

> The robot nodded its head, but did not expend its limited computing
> power on speech

So the robot *could* speak, but chose not to (much like students).

I have a feeling it's from an Asimov short story (possibly a Susan Calvin one?), but I haven't managed to identify it. Does anyone where it comes from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is from "[Catch that Rabbit](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47564)" (1944) by, of course, Isaac Asimov.

> He compromised. "Look, pal," he said, "I'm going to ask you to do some hard thinking and then you can go back to your boss."
>
> The "finger" nodded its head stiffly, but **did not exert its limited brain-power on speech**.

You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v32n06_1944-02_dtsg0318-LennyS/page/n158/mode/1up) in the original printing in *Astounding*, February 1944.

(While it is an Asimov robots story, it's a Donovan & Powell story, not a Susan Calvin story.)

Comment: Yes, that's it! Hopefully I can get rid of this "brain-worm" now...